# Does the future generated from boost::packaged_task throw wrong exception?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I find out there are an obviously different behaviors between boost::packaged_task and std::packaged_task. I had tested the boost version 1.55 and 1.56, and the c++11 compilers are Visual Studio 2013 and gcc(in XCode).

That is, the calling `get()` of the `future` generated from `packaged_task::get_future()` emits different exceptions.

Here is my simple code:

```
#include <boost/thread/future.hpp>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>

struct my_error {};

void throw_something()
{
    throw my_error();
}

int main()
{
    typedef boost::packaged_task<void> packaged_task;

    packaged_task task(throw_something);
    auto fu = task.get_future();
    task();

    try {

        fu.get();

        std::cout << "no exception" << std::endl;
    }
    catch (const my_error&) {
        std::cout << "catch my_error" << std::endl;
    } catch (const std::exception &e) {
        std::cout << "catch std::exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    } catch (...) {
        std::cout << "catch unknown error" << std::endl;
    }

    std::system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

In Visual Studio 2013 the result is:  **catch std::exception: Unknown exception**

and in gcc(in XCode) is: **catch std::exception: std::exception**

But if I changed the type of packaged_task to c++11 provided by Visual Studio 2013 or gcc, that's:

```
 typedef std::packaged_task<void()> packaged_task;
```

The result becomes difference: **catch my_error**

I think `std::packaged_task` works correctly because I can catch the really type. Do I misuse `boost::packaged_task`?

Answer (score 0):

A key difference could be that the standard library packaged_task might be statically linked, and the boost::thread version is linked in dynamically.

Throwing exceptions across dynamic library boundaries may not always work, especially when the sources weren't compiled with exactly the same compiler options.

You could

- check that the libraries were compiled with the same flags
- use the static version of Boost Thread library (BOOST_THREAD_STATIC, BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB might be related from a quick a google), See also http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/tutorial/linkage.html